# Printing an integer in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to print an integer with this code but when i assemble with tasm and run program.exe in dosbox, nothing happens and i think it goes into an infinite loop. Do you have an idea?

```
data segment para public 'data'
data ends

mycode segment para public 'code'
assume cs:mycode, ds:data

main proc far

    push ds
    xor ax, ax
    push ax
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov ax, 123
    mov cx, 0
    
    loop_count:
        mov bl, 10
        inc cx
        div bl
        mov dl, al
        mov al, ah
        xor ah, ah
        push ax
        xor ah, ah
        mov ax, dx
        cmp ax, 0
        jne loop_count
    
    
    loop_print:
        pop dx
        add dx, 30h
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h
        loop loop_print
        
ret

main endp
mycode ends
end main
```

Comment: `mov ax, dx` <-- surely that should be `mov al, dl`? Also, you already cleared `ah` before the `push`. No need to do it again directly afterwards.

Comment: Single-step your code with a debugger and look at registers. Specifically DH, which you never zero even though you copy DX to AX as the dividend for the next iteration of division.  `div bl` does `AX / BL`, not just `AL/BL`.  IDK if you were mixing it up with `div bx` which would write the remainder to DX?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a detailed explanation about printing an integer in [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos).

> ```
> mov dl, al    ; Preserve quotient
> mov al, ah    ; \
> xor ah, ah    ;  Store a 'cleaned' remainder
> push ax       ; /
> xor ah, ah
> mov ax, dx    ; Restore quotient
> ```

You want to store the current remainder on the stack, and you want to store it in a 'cleaned' fashion (with its high byte zero). Because both quotient and remainder are in the `AX` register, you had to first preserve the current quotient in another register like `DL`, but for the restoration you used the whole `DX` register with no guarantee that `DH` would be empty! This produced a runaway loop.

You can solve this in a number of ways, but I think you should not try to 'clean' what you push on the stack. Use the second loop where you need the character in `DL` anyway.

This is how printing the byte in `AL` looks like:

```
  mov  al, 123

  mov  bl, 10
  mov  cx, sp
loop_count:
  xor  ah, ah
  div  bl
  push ax           ; Remainder is in AH, don't care about AL
  test al, al
  jnz  loop_count
    
loop_print:
  pop  ax           ; Remainder is in AH, don't care about AL
  mov  dl, ah
  add  dl, '0'
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h
  cmp  sp, cx
  jb   loop_print
```

Comment: Note that a line comment ending in backslash may be a problem for some assemblers, at least for NASM.